Movie where husband realizes wife is a psychopath
I saw it about 7 years ago. It is a comedy, drama, and thriller. 
It is about this family: a wife, husband and their 2(?) children, where everything appears good and happy on the surface. Then the wife accidentally kills this guy and decides to take the body back to the house. She then tries to make a plan to get rid of the body but the husband discovers her and the body.
After freaking out they decide to get rid of the body together.
They try to maintain their normal facade, but the husband grows weary and eventually scared of his wife because she so easily and remorselessly was able to cope with the situation. 
Near the end of the movie the wife starts to plot something at an afternoon party at their house. 
In the end their house gets blown up, I'm unsure of who did it and who was still inside.

was it American?  how did you watch it, tv, theatre, dvd, etc?  was it live action, color?

Yes it could've been American, I watched it on TV and it was in color

ok, you might edit in more details.  also, can you happen to remember what channel you watched it on?

sorry no I can't remember, but my best guess would be it was on mnet
